# Test node failure

Tags: cardano-node

I successfully setup a testnet node over the weekend, all was running fine - I was able to create wallets and perform transactions etc.
However when I try to run the node today I am getting some errors, I haven't changed any config, I literally just turned the machine off and when I booted back up it didn't work (see error at the bottom)

I have downloaded the latest config files, I also deleted some data from the immutable folder in /db  - it synced up again but then gave the same error

I hope someone can help, many thanks in advance.

**Environment**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

cardano-node 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf

cardano-cli 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf

cabal-install version 3.4.0.0
compiled using version 3.4.0.0 of the Cabal library 

The GHCup Haskell installer, version v0.1.16.2
```

**Startup command**

```
cardano-node run \
   --topology /home/adam/dev/cardano-node/relay/testnet-topology.json \
   --database-path /home/adam/dev/cardano-node/db \
   --socket-path /home/adam/dev/cardano-node/relay/node.socket \
   --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
   --port 1337 \
   --config /home/adam/dev/cardano-node/relay/testnet-config.json
```

**Errors**

```
[HPE-LX-M:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:824] [2021-09-01 23:23:22.35 UTC] IP 3.129.133.68:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[HPE-LX-M:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:1037] [2021-09-01 23:23:22.55 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 18.132.238.21:3001 MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"
[HPE-LX-M:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:824] [2021-09-01 23:23:22.55 UTC] IP 18.132.238.21:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s
[HPE-LX-M:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:1035] [2021-09-01 23:23:22.69 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 3.124.178.139:3001 MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"
[HPE-LX-M:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:824] [2021-09-01 23:23:22.69 UTC] IP 3.124.178.139:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s
```

Comment: Out of mere curiosity, why 1.27.0 and no 1.29.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today the Alonzo hardfork was done on the Testnet, you should update your `cardano-node` and `cardano-cli` to version 1.29.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I don't know exactly what this is about. But I just deleted the whole db folder and created node.socket again. Resync, then it's back

Comment: Thanks all, I will update later and try again and let you know how it goes

Comment: All sorted, thanks for the heads up; guess I'd better start keeping up with the updates!